# Partial View rendering not correctly (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have modal dialog opening by click

Modal body is Partial View

Here is code of partial view

```
<div style="height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll">
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" , placeholder="Enter First and Last Name " />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sex" , placeholder="Sex" />
</div>
```

I call modal in main View like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addPatient" style="z-index: 5" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p style="font-size: 20px;">Appointment successfully created </p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/PatientDatabase/AddingPatient.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

But my inputs displaying in one row.

Like this

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipjdj.png)

Where problem can be?

As I understood it must display not in one row.

Comment: That depends entirely on the CSS you use to style the inputs, specifically these classes : `.form-group`, and / or `.form-group input`

Comment: Create fiddle for us

Comment: my guess is one of these has `display:inline`, or `float:left`, which could be solved either by adding `<br />`  tags at the end of your form groups, or adding something like `style="clear:both"`

Comment: also, the HTML you posted is incomplete, in your partial i am missing a `</div>` closing tag

Comment: You need to render your `partial view` in `modal-body` and add `Appointment successfully created ` in modal `modal-title` .

Comment: @mmushtaq where does that `modal-title` come from? i don't see it anywhere in OP's code, and making blind assumptions like that is dangerous.

Comment: This might be due to that you are rendering partial view in modal-footer

Comment: @TimothyGroote I am suggesting OP to do it through standard way.

Comment: @mmushtaq you can only make assumptions on the part of OP's code you are *not seeing*. my advise is ; try not to do that, or try to do it as little as possible ; you might be giving out bad advise without knowing it.

Comment: @TimothyGroote My assumption is that OP has placed `partial view contents` in `modal-footer` section which is incorrect (*[ref Modal Components](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#modal-components)*) because `modal-footer` has different styling properties which might cause that unexpected behavior.

Comment: @mmushtaq no, that is an assertion ; your assumption is that bootstrap is involved at all, for which there is no guarantee. your other assumption is that `modal-footer` has different styling properties

Answer (score 1):

Hope there is `float : left` in form-group class. So add `clear:both` in those div's style attribute.

```
<div style="height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll">
    <div class="form-group" style="clear:both;text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" , placeholder="Enter First and Last Name " />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="clear:both;text-align:center;padding-bottom: 20px; padding-top: 10px;">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sex" , placeholder="Sex" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't hope anything. you're a developer, you can make sure you know it.

Comment: I don't hope anything in mycode boss.  If somebody did't give me full code then, I can only hope. :( @TimothyGroote